# Android Studio 2.2 Databinding error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin

I've just updated Android Studio to `2.2`, Gradle plugin to `2.2.0` and I am getting the following error in the project when initializing views using `DataBinding`. It says `Type T has incompatible upper bounds`. Android Studio offers no suggestions on how to fix this. Casting the binding to the exact class doesn't solve the issue.

[image: getting this error]

It still compiles and runs though, but project is full of red errors - one for each `DataBinding` initialization. Any ideas?

Comment: If you switch from `DataBindingUtil` to your generated binding class (looks like it should be `FragmentTimelineOverlayBinding`), do you get better results?

Comment: @CommonsWare not quite, it seems as though the parameters don't match up to expected `(LayoutIflater, ViewGroup, int, DataBindingComponent)`

Comment: You should have a three-parameter `inflate()` method as an option on `FragmentTimelineOverlayBinding`. I just fired up one of my book samples in AS 2.2 with Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2.0, and `RowBinding.inflate(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), parent, false)` is recognized and compiles (where my layout is `row.xml`).

Comment: Using the 3 parameter `inflate()` override resolves the error. I guess I'll just change it everywhere in the project.

Comment: Please file a bug against Android Studio.

Comment: I just cloned one of my book samples, changed it to use the `DataBindingUtil.inflate()` that you are, and I do not get the Android Studio error. So, I cannot reproduce this, to file the bug that George Mount suggests. If you can create a project that reproduces the problem, [file an issue](http://b.android.com).

Comment: @CommonsWare are you also using the latest Gradle plugin (`2.2.0`)? When I revert the build tools to previous version, the problem disappears.

Comment: Yes, I am using plugin 2.2.0 with Gradle 2.14.1. After all, Android Studio 2.2 whines if you don't. :-)

Comment: I have been playing with this on and off today, and I am getting more "errors" that still compile and run fine. Namely, I get lots of `<binding>.getRoot() //cannot resolve method getRoot()`. I think it's more related to Gradle 2.14.1 than to Gradle plugin. I double checked and reverting just the Gradle plugin doesn't help.

Comment: My project is working. Can you give full code?

Answer (score 6):

1. open gradle-wrapper.properties
2. update distributionUrl 
   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-all.zip
3. File->Invalidate Caches/Restart
4. Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Just doing the step 3 resolved all the issues for me. +1, thank you! If you edit your answer to remove the first 2 steps, I'll accept it.

Comment: Not working for me: "cannot find symbol class BR" when launch

Answer (score 0):

My project is working.

```
   private LoadImageByPicassoBinding mBinding;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //mBinding = LoadImageByPicassoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.load_image_by_picasso, container, false);
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio 2.2 - I had to do Maksim's solution + executing `./gradlew` in the terminal to make the .gradle directory pull the 3.1 gradle version in order to make everything work.